# Set Content Inside Bootstrap modal popup

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I want show my all content inside bootstrap Modal Body.But It is going out side to modal body.

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="blockModel">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Blocked Users</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                    <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 1</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 2</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 3</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 4</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 5</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 6</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 1</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 7</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

                     <span class="blocktag label label-info">
                        <span >Tag 8</span>
                        <a  title="Remove" class="unblockUsers"><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i></a>
                    </span>

        </div>

    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>

</div>
```

Modal body should automatically expand it height, when body content is large.

**[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/tzsmhaLb/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should obey Bootstrap's architecture. It will lead you to less bugs. If you make use of its rows and columns classes, you will be able to scale and maintain these modals more efficitently.

Between your modal-body and the content, add a row, and a column size like this:

```
       <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              ...my content here...
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

The benefit to this is if you ever want to split this content, you will be able to do so with its `col-xs-*` classes. ***Maintainability*** is key when using Bootstrap ;)

See your [**jfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/tzsmhaLb/5/) using Bootstrap's Architecture

Comment: I went for a quick fix in the answer above, but you should follow this advice.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKeyes, I could tell you were doing the quick and easy fix. I'd be lying if I said I haven't done it myself, but mostly temporarily to move on to more pressing issues in my code and then I go back and fix it the right way. In the OP's case, since he's presumably learning, it would better if he learned the correct way of doing things :)

Answer (score 2):

As your `.blocktag` spans are floated left, they are rendered outside their container. You can add `clearfix` to the `modal-body` to prevent that from happening:

```
<div class="modal-body clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what worked for me:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisG87/tzsmhaLb/4/)

What I changed was adding

```
height: auto;
```

to .model-dialog on bootstrap.min.css line 7.

Then to model-body on bootstrap.min.css line 7.

```
display: inline-block;
height: 100%;
```

I hope that helps you!